# nsset valueforkey returns with "{( the value I need )}"

Tags: ios, core-data, nsset

In CoreData this returns me text i need placed between `{( ... )}`

```
NSSet *abc = self.file.abc;
NSString *name = [abc valueForKey:@"name"];

cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name ];
```

How to get the correct text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `valueForSet:` on a set, it returns "a set containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` on each of the receiving set's members."

This means that your name variable is actually pointing to a set instead of a string.

What you are seeing is simply the string description of a set.

---

Assuming that your set only contains one object, you can get that to that object by calling `anyObject` on the set. Then you can get the name of that object.

Comment: and how can I get the string?

Comment: Assuming that the object has a "name" property (which it seams to do, since the set invokes valueForKey: on the object) then you can get the name by calling valueForKey: on the "any" object. Assuming that the name property is a string, you will get a string back when you do that.

Comment: I've made this 'NSString *name = [[eds valueForKey:@"name"] anyObject];'

Comment: You could also do `NSString *name = [[yourSet anyObject] valueForKey:@"name"];`. That way you don't have to get all the names and discard them. It won't make a difference if the set only contains one object though.